# Starting WebAgent as a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, gridgain

I am trying to deploy GridGain Web Console with Docker and also with web agent in docker-compose.yml file. I tried it according to this guide https://www.gridgain.com/docs/web-console/latest/deploying-web-console-docker, but web-agent is not part of docker deployment.

I tried to modify docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  backend:
    image: gridgain/gridgain-web-console-backend:2020.05.00
    # Restart on crash.
    restart: always
    environment:
      # Mail settings
      #- SPRING_MAIL_HOST=
      #- SPRING_MAIL_PORT=
      #- SPRING_MAIL_USERNAME=
      #- SPRING_MAIL_PASSWORD=
      - JVM_OPTS=
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/Users:/opt/gridgain-web-console-server/work
  frontend:
    depends_on:
      - backend
    image: gridgain/gridgain-web-console-frontend:2020.05.00
    ports:
      # Proxy HTTP nginx port (HOST_PORT:DOCKER_PORT)
      - 80:8008
    container_name: frontend
  webagent:
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
    image: gridgain/gridgain-web-agent:2020.05.00
    environment:
      - TOKENS=59f9d111-eaad-405b-a3c8-310e9245f943
      - SERVER_URI=frontend:80
```

And it does not work. Always web agent is not able to connect to server(GridGain console). I run it via `docker-compose up`

I get following stacktrace:

```
webagent_1  | [2020-08-29T12:03:56,213][INFO ][Connect thread][WebSocketRouter] Connecting to server: frontend:80
webagent_1  | [2020-08-29T12:03:56,220][WARN ][Connect thread][AgentUtils] Failed to configure proxy.
webagent_1  | java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 6: https:
webagent_1  |   at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
webagent_1  |   at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(URI.java:2854) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
webagent_1  |   at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3057) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
webagent_1  |   at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:673) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
webagent_1  |   at org.gridgain.console.agent.AgentUtils.configureProxy(AgentUtils.java:156) ~[gridgain-web-console-agent-2020.05.00.jar:?]
webagent_1  |   at org.gridgain.console.agent.handlers.WebSocketRouter.connect0(WebSocketRouter.java:225) ~[gridgain-web-console-agent-2020.05.00.jar:?]
webagent_1  |   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_242]
webagent_1  |   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_242]
webagent_1  |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_242]
webagent_1  |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_242]
webagent_1  |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_242]
webagent_1  | [2020-08-29T12:03:57,032][ERROR][Connect thread][WebSocketRouter] Failed to establish websocket connection with server: frontend:80
webagent_1  | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme must be 'ws' or 'wss'
```

Question is how to correct connect webagent to gridgain console. I mean something important is missing in 'webagent' service in docker file, but I do not know what.
Have you any suggestion for resolving of my issue?
Thanks for everything.

Comment: According to your config the web console is on 8008 port internally. Did you try `- SERVER_URI=http://frontend:8008` ?

Comment: yes, I did, same problem

Comment: @Martin, check this section of the docs. You need to enable the ignite-http-rest module on the cluster name and write down the address of the backend/frontend in the agent's config file: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/web-console/latest/deploying-web-console-docker#starting-the-web-agent

Btw, WebConsole is being substituted by its successor Control Center. So, it's probably better if you switch to Control Center right away: https://www.gridgain.com/docs/control-center/latest/overview

Comment: @dmagda thank you, reason why I do not use Control Center is that I use apache ignite 2.7.5 which is not supported by Control Center. My problem is not connection between  ignite cluster and ignite console, but between  web console and ignite web agent. Everything works if it runs like local application, my problem is in configuration of  ''webagent" service in my docker file. I mean I am missing some configuration regarding proxy, something is missing in webagent service.

Comment: @Martin, what exception did you get after setting this address - SERVER_URI=http://frontend:80?

Comment: @dmagda I always get same exception with port 80 and port 8008 as well. I pasted stacktrace in to question above.: [Connect thread][AgentUtils] Failed to configure proxy.
webagent_1  | java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 6: https: . But problem was with web agent token as Andrey answered  in his answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong uri  for the web console in the agent, please use `SERVER_URI=http://frontend:8008`

To get a token for agent you can only run web console `docker-compose up -d backend frontend`

- register a user
- open the profile page and copy the token
- setting `TOKENS` in the web agent
- startup agent `docker-compose up -d webagent`

But I can't find `NODE_URI` in your configuration file. By default agent will try to connect to `http://localhost:8080`, which is unreachable in web agent container.

Comment: thank you Andrey, I tried several SERVER_URI, but root cause was incorrect token as you mentioned.I did not try rewrite NODE_URI yet, but yes, I will rewrite it. Thanks.